# Android App Cannot connect to Rocket Chat server

Tags: android, ssl, nginx, rocket.chat

I followed the below guide to setup Rocket Chat:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-configure-and-deploy-rocket-chat-on-ubuntu-14-04

It works as expected through the browser.

When trying to connect it to the Android Mobile App downloaded from the play store, the message received is that it cannot connect.  SSL cert is from Let's Encrypt.

From searching online I am at a loss if it is the let's encrypt cert that is the issue or something else?  I have been using Let's Encrypt on other projects without issue.

Is there some in particular that I am required to enter into the NGINX reverse proxy?

Comment: Recommend running your site through something like: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because your web server is not updated, try updating it and see if works. Look at this warning the apps repositories:

> Make sure your server supports WebSocket. These are the minimum requirements for Apache 2.4 and Nginx 1.3 or greater.

For more information:

- [iOS repository](https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat.iOS)
- [Android repository](https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat.Android)